# Can I license a project that I have built on if it already has a license?

Tags: cc-by, relicensing

**Scenario**
I am building off of a project that was released under the Creative Commons BY license. Now that my project is done, I want to release my version of the product under my own license.

**Question:**
Is this possible?

- If yes do I need permission?
- If no what limitation do I have?

Comment: Do you really mean your **own** license, or simply a different one?

Comment: just a different one that it was originally released under

Comment: But it could be my own as well.

Comment: I think just treat the OP's license as if it were a typical outside license.

Comment: yeah that would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The CC-BY license is one of their more permissive licenses: it simply requires attributing the original author.

So: **no** you don't need permission. You simply need to include, somewhere in your finished product (perhaps an about or credits screen) the name of the author and preferably a link back to where you found it.

There is **no Share Alike** restriction on the CC-BY license, so you are not forced to keep the same license: you can thus choose to relicense your product as you wish.